# how to develpoe nested loop format

Tags: c#, .net, json

i am trying to develop below format json.

```
{
    "contacts":[
    {
        "id":"c200",
        "name":"Ravi Tamada",
        "email":"ravi@gmail.com",
        "address":"xx-xx-xxxx,x - street, x - country",
        "gender":"male",
        "phone":[
        {
            "Section":"International"
        }]       
    }]
}
```

using  below i have used my programs

```
public class Cont
{   
    public string sno { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string em { get; set; }
    public string address { get; set; }
    public string gender { get; set; }
    // public Phone phone   = new Phone();  
    public List<Phone> phone { get; set; }
    // Phone = new Phone();
}

public class Phone
{
    public string Section { get; set; }
}    

public class RootObject
{
    public List<Cont> contacts { get; set; }
}
```

here i pass all the values,all values comming from database

```
ContCollection.Add(new Cont()
{
    sno = dr["Cinema"].ToString(),
    name = dr["Gallery"].ToString(),
    address = dr["star"].ToString(),
    gender = dr["video"].ToString(),
    em = "",
    /how can i use  List<Phone> here 
});
```

please anyone explain me

Thanks and Regards

Comment: how are you getting the data from the DB, is it a comma delimited field on the current reader, do you make a seperate call?

Comment: i have separate method for db

Comment: What is wrong with the answers in your previous questions?

Comment: I agree, answers in the other question seem reasonable to me.

Comment: previously phone object only.but i need phone is array of object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An example on how to parse any object to JSON using native .NET 4.0

```
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;
public static class JsonParser() {
     public string ParseJson(object obj) {
     return new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(obj);
     }
}
```

As for your how can you use List here depends how your database is modelled and how you are retrieving the values from the database.

I'm expecting you are using ADO.NET here.
In that case you need to create a second query to retrieve the phonenumbers once you've received your first data. (You should add some code on how you did that.)
E.g. Select PhoneNumbers From PhoneNumberTable Where ID="---yourId---"

```
//Query code here
while(dr.read()) {
var cont = new Cont() { 
  sno = dr["Cinema"].ToString(),
//... and so on.
}
cont.PhoneNumbers = new List<Phone>();
//Add another query here to retrieve the phonenumbers for the current item.
while(dr2.read()) {
var pho = new PhoneNumber()
{ section = dr["Number"];}
cont.PhoneNumbers.Add(pho);
}
ContCollection.Add(cont);

}
```

The above pseudo code should give you an idea.

Comment: Thanks for give Great idae

Answer (score 1):

The containing structure isn't a loop, so this isn't a nested loop.  Indeed, the containing structure isn't a series of imperative code statements, so you can't even put a loop here.

This is an object initializer:

```
new Cont()
{
    sno = dr["Cinema"].ToString(),
    name = dr["Gallery"].ToString(),
    address = dr["star"].ToString(),
    gender = dr["video"].ToString(),
    em = ""
}
```

So all you can do is initialize the property:

```
new Cont()
{
    sno = dr["Cinema"].ToString(),
    name = dr["Gallery"].ToString(),
    address = dr["star"].ToString(),
    gender = dr["video"].ToString(),
    em = "",
    phone = someList
}
```

In this case `someList` can be anything which evaluates to a `List<Phone>`.  For example:

```
new List<Phone>();
```

However, it looks like you're pulling this data from a database record of some kind.  Where do you get the phone data?  In a normalized structure you'd likely get it from a separate table, so it wouldn't be part of the `dr` object.  If that's the case, where is it?  Or is it a delimited string value in a field on the `dr` object?

Basically, you have a few options.  If you can fetch the phone data in the current context then you can potentially transform it into an enumeration to build your list.  For example, if it's a pipe-delimited string:

```
phone = dr["phones"].ToString().Split('|').Select(p => new Phone() { Section = p }).ToList()
```

This grabs the delimited string, splits it on the delimiter (turning it into an enumeration of strings), uses `Select()` to transform that enumeration of strings into an enumeration of `Phone` objects, and calls `ToList()` to evaluate that enumeration into a list for the `phone` property.

If, on the other hand, you can't get the phone data from the current context, then you may need to loop over that data.  If that's the case then you'd turn your one-line `.Add()` into a couple of lines:

```
var cont = new Cont()
{
    sno = dr["Cinema"].ToString(),
    name = dr["Gallery"].ToString(),
    address = dr["star"].ToString(),
    gender = dr["video"].ToString(),
    em = "",
    phone = new List<Phone>();
};
foreach (var phone in someListOfPhones)
    cont.phone.Add(phone);
ContCollection.Add(cont);
```

Looking at that structure, it seems likely that there must be *some* way to get `someListOfPhones` in that context, but we can't know for sure since you haven't specified it.  Either way, your choices are to generate the list of phones from the current context or separate the code into multiple statements to hold a loop.

Side note: I recommend initializing the `phone` property in the `Cont` object's constructor:

```
public Cont()
{
    phone = new List<Phone>();
}
```

This will allow consuming code to access that property without first having to manually initialize it, which would otherwise result in a `NullReferenceException`.